# How do I stop Chrome 31.0.1612.1 dev-m Aura from opening in Windows 8 mode?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I've installed Dev Channel Chrome version 31.0.1612.1 dev-m Aura, and by accident I clicked the option to re-launch the browser in Windows 8 mode. I've found answers saying that there should be a corresponding option in the Chrome menu to re-launch the browser in desktop mode, but I can't see any such option! I've also tried to edit the registry, to no effect.

This is what my Chrome menu looks like:

[image: Chrome Menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opening chrome from metro screen will take you to the windows 8 mode. in (Version 31.0.1612.1 dev-m Aura). Try launching from the desktop (if u've some shortcuts on desktop) it'll work.. It worked for me..

Comment: If this is how Chrome will work in the future, I'm pretty annoyed. I don't want to use Chrome in Windows 8 mode at all, and I always launch it from the start screen :(

Comment: **UPDATE** Google withdrawn the Aura update. Just update the chrome, and you're fine. no more annoying windows 8 mode :)

Comment: Aura is back it seems, and Windows 8 mode :(

Comment: Yeah! its back.. But with bugs fixed. No keyboard issues so far. If you do not want to open in metro mode, launch it from desktop. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm now starting it from the desktop :(

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Chrome completely (ticking the checkbox to remove all browser data) seemed to help, since Chrome now acts normally after reinstalling. The strange thing though is that the version string changed to 31.0.1612.2 dev-m (the Aura bit disappeared), even though I installed Dev Channel again.

Googling a bit on Aura, it seems it might've been a buggy update (maybe it was withdrawn promptly!?). I did notice that it wasn't responding to the keyboard in Windows 8 mode.

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem on aura build, the keyboard didnt respond so the ****.1 dev-m got updated to ****.2 dev-m and there is no Chrome OS-like UI and the word "aura" at the end of build in chrome://chrome tab.. hope it will soon get fixed and aura will soon be back